# Custom Chrome URL suggestions

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

One of the neat things about Chrome is that, if you type a word on the address bar, it suggests what relevant URLs might be. For example if I type "New York", it suggests nytimes.com

Can an extension be developed that provides customized suggestions? For instance, if I have an internal company website, say foo which hosts documents with numeric IDs - say http://domain.com/123 or http://domain.com/234. When someone types "123" on the browser address bar, I want http://domain.com/123 to show as a suggestion (even if it has never been accessed before).

Is something like this possible? If so, I would love some pointers (I've never developed a Chrome extension, but if possible, I can look things up and get this implemented).

Thanks!
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through Omnibox, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html
I have written a sample implementation here :

```
Manifest File:

{

 "name": "Omnibox Demo",

  "description" : "This is used for demonstrating Omnibox",

  "version": "1",

  "background": {

    "scripts": ["background.js"]

  },

  "omnibox": {
 "keyword" : "demo" 
},

  "manifest_version": 2

}

JS File:

chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({"description":"Search %s in Dev Source Code"});

chrome.omnibox.onInputStarted.addListener(function() {

    console.log("Input Started");


});

chrome.omnibox.onInputCancelled.addListener(function() {

    console.log("Input Cancelled");

});

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function (text) {
    console.log("Input Entered is " + text);
});

chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(

  function(text, suggest) {

    console.log('inputChanged: ' + text);

    suggest([

      {content: text + " one", description: "the first one"},
      {content: text + " number two", description: "the second entry"}
    ]);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate this!